# Selecting string after the last \\ using regex with Impala SQL

Tags: sql, regex, impala

I have a dataset with a column with processes and the path.  I am trying to use regex with Impala to strip off the executable.  The dataset looks like this:

```
C:\\Windows\\System32\\svchost.exe
C:\\Windows\\System32\\conhost.exe
C:\\Windows\\System32\\net1.exe
C:\\Windows\\System32\\schtasks.exe
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Citrix\\ICA Client\\SelfServicePlugin\\SelfService.exe
C:\\Windows\\System32\\backgroundTaskHost.exe
C:\\Windows\\System32\\net.exe
C:\\Windows\\System32\\conhost.exe
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Wireless AutoSwitch\\wrlssw.exe
```

Desired output:

```
svchost.exe
conhost.exe
net1.exe
schtasks.exe
SelfService.exe
backgroundTaskHost.exe
net.exe
conhost.exe
wrlssw.exe
```

I have tried many queries like the two below but keep running into errors

```
select regexp_extract(w.destinationprocessname, '([^\\]+)$')
from winworkstations_realtime w
where w.externalid = '4688'
limit 10
```

Error:

```
AnalysisException: No matching function with signature: regexp_replace(STRING, STRING).

select regexp_extract(w.destinationprocessname, '\\(?:.(?!\\))+$',0)
from winworkstations_realtime w
where w.externalid = '4688'
limit 10
```

Error:

```
Could not compile regexp pattern: \(?:.(?!\))+$ Error: invalid perl operator: (?!
```

Looking for some guidance from anyone that is good with impala or regex.

Comment: You know what version of ImpalaSQL are you using? Maybe `regex_replace` was only implemented in a newer version...

Comment: statestored version 2.10.0-cdh5.13.0 RELEASE @AdrianoValente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not being a regex expert, I am sure there is a better way but this does the work

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_extract("C:\\\Windows\\\\System32\\\\svchost.exe", ".+(\\\\.+)$", 1), "\\\\", "");
```